# Cut Off My Own Google Cloud Engine SSH Nose

Tags: ssh, password, google, serial, keys

A bit of stupidity. On my Google Compute Engine (GCE) instance, I went in and changed the sshd_config to listen another port (something I do routinely)...but I didn't test before logging off.  And there's a typo. So now I can't log in via ssh because the config is screwed up and sshd won't even start. (I can launch sshd with a different config file, as a non-root user, but it gives me a "Could not load host key", as expected, probably doesn't have the permissions.)

Use the GCE serial console you say? Ah... but none of the users I can login with are sudoers. (I have two others with sudo'er, but the passwords aren't working, don't know why. I wrote them down wrong?)

So I have user (non-root) access with password, and have keys for root (sudo'er) users, I just don't have a way to log in with those thru the serial console?  (Is there a way to have the console recognize my keys instead of a password?)

It's good for security that I can't just fix this in 5 minutes with my limited knownledge, but can I leverage what I have to get back in with root? I have the access to the project in the Google Compute Engine Console and the users, etc., I just have cut myself off from command line on this instance.

If it were a physical machine, I'd stick in bootable usb distro and simply edit config file and restart.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have console access, you should be able to boot the system into single user mode and correct the ssh configuration.

Comment: Great suggestion larsks, thank you.  I know how to do this on a physical machine. As noted, this is about a Google Cloud Engine instance, so where/how do you do that for an instance in GCE? I've Googled, but I can't find that anywhere.

Comment: I'm not actually certain (I'm not a GCE user), but you said that you had access to a serial console, in which case the process should be the same as for a physical machine: while connected to the console, reboot the machine, and then see if it's possible to interrupt the bootloader.

Comment: There is some documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To edit or examine configuration files in the root disk of a VM that you do not have access, follow the steps in the section ¨Inspect an instance without shutting it down¨ of [this document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting).

A summary of the steps:

1) [Create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create) a temporal VM you can SSH into.

2) [Create a copy](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/disks/create) of the root disk that is failing (this would have to be from a snapshot). You can actually [delete](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/delete) the original VM and keep the disks (-keep-disks=all) but I would rather work with a copy.

3) [Attach](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/attach-disk) the copy of the disk to the temporal VM and mount the disk you wish to examine.

4) Modify the config files. [Detach](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/detach-disk) the modified disk and [spin](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create) a new VM using this disk.

Comment: Thanks Carlos.  Seemed like a lot of work when I thought about it, and wasn't sure it would work. With your guidance and knowledge that it would work in the end, was not so hard. I guess if there were a way to change the file directly, that would represent a security issue.

Comment: I am glad it worked. I believe the serial console approach would have worked if you had been able to log with a sudoer.